# How can I record a conversation in c#

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I have a app which has to record a conversation. The outgoing sound in one channel and incoming sound on other channel. and finally save the recording to 1 stereo file(mp3 file).

I was going through [handling-multi-channel-audio-in-naudio](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.in/2012/01/handling-multi-channel-audio-in-naudio.html). But could not get to work for me yet. Here is what I tried, the code below save a sound recording in a wav file. It doesn't handle multi channel functionality. I am unable to incorporate multi channel functionality in my code:

```
private void Save_Wav(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sourceList.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;

    SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
    save.Filter = "Wave File (*.wav)|*.wav;";
    if (save.ShowDialog() != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) return;

    int deviceNumber = sourceList.SelectedItems[0].Index;

    sourceStream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn();
    sourceStream.DeviceNumber = deviceNumber;
    sourceStream.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(44100, NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(deviceNumber).Channels);

    sourceStream.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs>(sourceStream_DataAvailable);
    waveWriter = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter(save.FileName, sourceStream.WaveFormat);

    sourceStream.StartRecording();
}

private void sourceStream_DataAvailable(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
{
    if (waveWriter == null) return;

    waveWriter.WriteData(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
    waveWriter.Flush();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you tell us why it doesn't work? Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: I need help incorporating multi channel feature in my code.

Comment: Are you trying to merge two mono sources into a single stereo source? If so, make sure they're both identical (encoding, sample rate, bits) and interleave the samples.